# Android Studio [Code] -> [Convert Java File to Kotlin File] not working on large files

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm in the middle of conversion process for my project written in `Java` to `Kotlin`. The refactoring process was going pretty smoothly, I used to convert files with the <kbd>Code</kbd> -> <kbd>Convert Java File to Kotlin File</kbd> from Android Studio (*intellij IDEA*) menu, and then fix all the remaining problematic chunks manually. However, when I try to convert a really **large file (about 5000 lines of code), it just does nothing**. I'm using Android Studio version 3.5.3.

Comment: Does your Java file contain any hex format like `0x2C_3175C3` or something?

Comment: As a workaround, try it with the old converter. (uncheck "Use new Java to Kotlin converter" in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Kotlin).
Also please create an issue at http://kotl.in/issue with your IDE logs attached: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files and if possible a sample project (or at least the problematic file) to reproduce. Thanks.

Comment: Old converter worked, Thanks.

Comment: That option is not available on the new shitty Android Studio, any idea how to make it work? I already tried to re-install the IDE. Other than wiping my hard driving and re-installing the OS I can't see how can I make it work again.